# Convert a sound file from one audio codec to another when file called

Tags: windows, audio, encoding, codec

*I am not sure that this is the correct place for this question, so tell me if so and I will repost elsewhere.*

I have a rather large collection of music, most of which is encoded in FLAC format. Unfortunately the DJ software I use (Serato) does not support FLAC (I cannot for the life of me understand this, and I have spent years lobbying to add this feature, as have a significant part of their userbase, to no avail).

**Would it be possible to create a program that would sit between Serato and windows and when you dropped a FLAC file into Serato (or File-Load or whatever) it would convert that to mp3, store it in the temp folder and load that mp3 into Serato?**

**EDIT:** Converting to WAV would probably be simpler and quicker

Comment: Does Serato support drag/drop?  Could you make some window in the foreground above the Serato drag target that intercepts the drag/drop, and then posts the drag/drop to Serato later?  Also, you should decode to WAV rather than MP3.  It will be faster, and you won't lose quality.

Comment: You might also consider batch-converting to Apple lossless.  Yeah, I know, that'd be quite the mess, but it seems that Serato isn't going to support FLAC because of it:  http://serato.com/forum/discussion/248118

Comment: @brad indeed I just came back here because I realized that it makes far more sense to convert to wav. lossless -> lossless is just so much more sensible

Answer (score 2):

There is a filesystem that converts FLAC to mp3 behind the scenes. So even if the files are actually stored as FLAC, they look like mp3 to the applications. It's called [MP3FS](http://mp3fs.sourceforge.net/), and should be exactly what you're looking for.

Unfortunately, it's for Linux only as far as I know. You could try running a Linux system as a virtual machine and share the MP3FS files so the Windows system can access it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will certainly give that a try, but unfortunately that means that I would have to have a laptop with me - instead of being able to just bring a usb drive along to gigs.